# Integration of swagger API controller with MultipartFile in tests with JUnit 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, junit5, multipartfile

I´m new working with Spring Boot v2.3.0.RELEASE, Java 8, JUnit 5, and Swagger OAS 3, I try to test the integration of the API Controller (generated with swagger-codegen) with my service, this controller contains a unique method that allows upload file a gallery, but when I run the test this throws an exception at the moment that converts the file by the mapper.

I don´t understand why this is happening, I´m generating wrong the mock test of MultipartFile?

How to solve this problem?

**Class GaleriaAPIControllerTest**

```
package com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.swagger.api;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.builder.ArchivoBuilder;
import com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.builder.GaleriaBuilder;
import com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.builder.MultipartFileBuilder;
import com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.service.GaleriaService;
import com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.swagger.model.ArchivoDTO;
import com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.swagger.model.GaleriaDTO;
import com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.swagger.model.TipoGaleriaEnum;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.util.Collections;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyLong;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

class GaleriaApiControllerTest extends BaseControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    @Qualifier("GaleriaServiceImpl")
    private GaleriaService galeriaServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private GaleriaBuilder galeriaBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private ArchivoBuilder archivoBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private MultipartFileBuilder multipartFileBuilder;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MultipartFile multipartFile = multipartFileBuilder.create().build();
        archivoBuilder = archivoBuilder.createWithId().multipartFile(multipartFile);
        galeriaBuilder = galeriaBuilder.createWithId().tipo(TipoGaleriaEnum.GENERICA)
                .archivos(Collections.singletonList(archivoBuilder.build()));
    }

    @Test
    void createArchivoInGaleriaTest() throws Exception {
        GaleriaDTO galeria = galeriaBuilder.buildDTO();
        ArchivoDTO archivo = archivoBuilder.buildDTO();
        given(galeriaServiceImpl.addArchivoInGaleria(anyLong(), anyLong(), any())).willReturn(archivo);
        MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", "prueba.txt", "text/plain",
                multipartFileBuilder.build().getInputStream());
        mvc.perform(multipart("/galeria/" + galeria.getId() + "/archivo")
                .file(file)
                .param("archivoId", archivo.getId().toString())
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andDo(print());
    }
}
```

**Class BaseControllerTest**

```
package com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.swagger.api;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class BaseControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUpBase() {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }
}
```

**Class GaleriaAPI** (class created with swagger-codegen)

```
package com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.swagger.api;

import com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.swagger.model.ArchivoDTO;
import com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.swagger.model.GaleriaDTO;
import com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.swagger.model.MessageResponseDTO;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.swagger.annotations.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CookieValue;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
@Api(value = "galeria", description = "the galeria API")
public interface GaleriaApi {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GaleriaApi.class);

    default Optional<ObjectMapper> getObjectMapper(){
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    default Optional<HttpServletRequest> getRequest(){
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    default Optional<String> getAcceptHeader() {
        return getRequest().map(r -> r.getHeader("Accept"));
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Registar o actualiza un archivo", nickname = "createArchivoInGaleria", notes = "", response = ArchivoDTO.class, tags={ "galeria-api-controller", })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Archvio registrado y/o actualizado correctamente", response = ArchivoDTO.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 409, message = "Error de negocio", response = MessageResponseDTO.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Error interno", response = MessageResponseDTO.class) })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/galeria/{galeriaId}/archivo",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        consumes = { "multipart/form-data" },
        method = RequestMethod.POST)
    default ResponseEntity<ArchivoDTO> createArchivoInGaleria(@ApiParam(value = "", required=true) @RequestParam(value="archivoId", required=true)  Long archivoId
,@ApiParam(value = "file detail") @Valid @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file
,@ApiParam(value = "ID de la galeria",required=true) @PathVariable("galeriaId") Long galeriaId
) {
        if(getObjectMapper().isPresent() && getAcceptHeader().isPresent()) {
            if (getAcceptHeader().get().contains("application/json")) {
                try {
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(getObjectMapper().get().readValue("{\r\n  \"tipo\" : \"tipo\",\r\n  \"file\" : \"\",\r\n  \"length\" : 1,\r\n  \"id\" : 6,\r\n  \"nombre\" : \"nombre\"\r\n}", ArchivoDTO.class), HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Couldn't serialize response for content type application/json", e);
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                }
            }
        } else {
            log.warn("ObjectMapper or HttpServletRequest not configured in default GaleriaApi interface so no example is generated");
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
}
```

**Class ArchivoDTO** (class created with swagger-codegen)

```
package com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.swagger.model;

import java.util.Objects;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

/**
 * ArchivoDTO
 */
@Validated
public class ArchivoDTO   {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private Long id = null;

  @JsonProperty("nombre")
  private String nombre = null;

  @JsonProperty("tipo")
  private String tipo = null;

  @JsonProperty("file")
  private Resource file = null;

  @JsonProperty("length")
  private Long length = null;

  public ArchivoDTO id(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get id
   * @return id
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, readOnly = true, value = "")
      @NotNull

    public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public ArchivoDTO nombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get nombre
   * @return nombre
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
      @NotNull

    public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
  }

  public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
  }

  public ArchivoDTO tipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get tipo
   * @return tipo
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
      @NotNull

    public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
  }

  public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
  }

  public ArchivoDTO file(Resource file) {
    this.file = file;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get file
   * @return file
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
      @NotNull

    @Valid
    public Resource getFile() {
    return file;
  }

  public void setFile(Resource file) {
    this.file = file;
  }

  public ArchivoDTO length(Long length) {
    this.length = length;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get length
   * @return length
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
      @NotNull

    public Long getLength() {
    return length;
  }

  public void setLength(Long length) {
    this.length = length;
  }


  @Override
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    ArchivoDTO archivoDTO = (ArchivoDTO) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.id, archivoDTO.id) &&
        Objects.equals(this.nombre, archivoDTO.nombre) &&
        Objects.equals(this.tipo, archivoDTO.tipo) &&
        Objects.equals(this.file, archivoDTO.file) &&
        Objects.equals(this.length, archivoDTO.length);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, nombre, tipo, file, length);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class ArchivoDTO {\n");
    
    sb.append("    id: ").append(toIndentedString(id)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    nombre: ").append(toIndentedString(nombre)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    tipo: ").append(toIndentedString(tipo)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    file: ").append(toIndentedString(file)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    length: ").append(toIndentedString(length)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(java.lang.Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }
}
```

**Test Error**

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.swagger.model.ArchivoDTO["file"]->org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource["inputStream"])

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:183)
    at com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.swagger.api.GaleriaApiControllerTest.createArchivoInGaleriaTest(GaleriaApiControllerTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.swagger.model.ArchivoDTO["file"]->org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource["inputStream"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:293)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.navastud.apibackendcuentos.swagger.model.ArchivoDTO["file"]->org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource["inputStream"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:77)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.reportBadDefinition(SerializerProvider.java:1277)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:400)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.failForEmpty(UnknownSerializer.java:71)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.UnknownSerializer.serialize(UnknownSerializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:723)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:723)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:166)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1513)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:287)
    ... 95 more
```

Comment: The exception message says "`to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS`". Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried  objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS); but throws the same exception